# Trouble changing background image of parent div by hovering over child div in javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, background-image, mouseover

As my title explains, I have a background image I am using and want it to change when I hover over a div in a certain area of the page.

Currently my background image for `#main` is `4Era_home.jpg` and when I hover over `#television` I would like that background image to change to `4Era_home_tv.jpg`.

I hope this makes sense as I have been looking online but cannot find a solution that will work. I know that css will not work for this so any help with the jquery or javascript for this would help.

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="television">
        <a href="#" id="tv_glow">test</a>
    <div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have to back up that `css classes won't work` because CSS a large part of the solution.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by `I know that css will not work`. Does that mean you don't want to use CSS or you have tried a CSS only solution it didn't work? In general you would use CSS to specify the location of the images. You can then use jQuery to switch between the classes as required.

Comment: I meant that in most cases during my research, the websites I found with potential solutions all said that it could not be done with CSS alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CSS as well as jQuery.

Update your HTML to use a default class pointing to the default image, in te below example `home`:

```
<div id="main" class="home">
    <div id="television">
        <a href="#" id="tv_glow">television test</a>
    <div>
</div>​
```

Use CSS styles similar to the below to define the require images:
*(You can ginore the styles I used on `#main` they are just for the DEMO, the styles you are interested in are `.home` and `tv`)*

```
#main{
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  text-align: center; 
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
}

.home
{
  background-image:url('http://www.fileden.com/files/2012/6/19/3318010/Eraser.png');
}

.tv
{
  background-image:url('http://www.fileden.com/files/2012/6/19/3318010/Ok.png');
}
```

Switch classes using jQuery `toggleClass()` like this:

```
$("#television").hover(function() {
    var $parent = $(this).parent();
    $parent.toggleClass("home, tv");
}, function() {
    var $parent = $(this).parent();
    $parent.toggleClass("home, tv");
});​
```

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FranWahl/UACUW/) - Switching background image in parent element

Comment: I also added some border-styles to the `main` and `television` div in the DEMO. This makes it clearer that it is the `television` div which is hovered over to replace the image in the parent. Just to clarify, to use your images, simply replace the url values in the styles as required, using yours would not work in the DEMO off course.

Comment: Not sure why but it is just not working for me. I wrote it just like you did but I must be missing something.

Comment: I just uploaded the page the the server so you can look at all my code. What am I missing from yours? the small area where "test" is is where I want to hover over to change the background image you see in the red div.

Comment: @romclblu01: Open your broswer debugging tool and you can see in the console that you have a script error. `SyntaxError: Illegal Character });`. The script code you have looks right between lines 23 and 31, however, something in your `newHome` file is messing with the syntax.

Comment: Hey Francois thank you so much for your help, I have one last question and you do not have to answer it as you've already done plenty to help but I just wanted to know if to repeat the same process for the other divs I have on this page with their own specific backgrounds, do I just copy and past the code into the script but change the divs names? Like instead of home_tv.jpg I want to hover over the shirt div and have the BG change to home_shirt.jpg.

Comment: @romclblu01: I updated the original fiddle adding another div for shirts and another style and the required script. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var child = $( '#television' ),
    parent = child.parent();

child.hover( function(){
  parent.addClass( 'tv-image' );
}, function(){
  parent.removeClass( 'tv-image' );
});
```

CSS

```
.tv-image { background-image: url( 'path/to/4Era_home_tv.jpg' ); }
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple javascript solution based on the functions below is:

```
<a onmouseover="util.addClassName('main', 'tv-glow');"
   onmouseout="util.removeClassName('main', 'tv-glow')"
   href="...">test</a>
```

You may prefer to dynamically attach the listeners and could also have a "toggle" function that swaps the classes in and out.

Note that hover effects are pretty useless on touch screen devices.

Some functions that every developer should have in their toolbox:

```
var util = util || {};

util.hasClassName = function(el, cName) {
    if (typeof el == 'string') el = document.getElementById(el);

    var re = new RegExp('(^|\\s+)' + cName + '(\\s+|$)');
    return el && re.test(el.className);
}

util.addClassName = function(el, cName) {

    if (typeof el == 'string') el = document.getElementById(el);

    if (!util.hasClassName(el, cName)) {
        el.className = el.className + ' ' + cName;
    }
}

util.removeClassName = function(el, cName) {

    if (typeof el == 'string') el = document.getElementById(el);

    if (util.hasClassName(el, cName)) {
        var re = new RegExp('(^|\\s+)' + cName + '(\\s+|$)','g');
        el.className = el.className.replace(re, '');
    }
}
```